# Is there a method/function in c++ which later constant parameters are based on the first ones?

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameter-passing

The constant parameter list seems to be error. I want to use the last parameter based on the 1st one

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;        

template<class T>
int ExistIndex(const vector<T> v, T obj, int start = 0, int end = v.size() - 1)
{
    //The last parameter is the problem 
    //Finds the index where obj exists in the vector. If it does not 
    // -1 is returned. does not check for bounds
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {   
        //Finding the object
        if (v[i] == obj) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
      //Executing
      vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
      int l = ExistIndex(v1, 3);// Although this compiles

      cout << endl;
      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question some more?  It's very unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess `ExistIndex(a, b, c)` should call `ExistIndex(a, b, c, a.size() - 1)`.

Comment: ExistIndex(a, b, c) should call ExistIndex(a, b, c, a.size() - 1).  but does not call

Answer (score 3):

What you've written [does not compile for me](https://ideone.com/2xdkY5). I see:

```
prog.cpp:6:67: error: local variable ‘v’ may not appear in this context
 int ExistIndex(const vector<T> v, T obj, int start = 0, int end = v.size() - 1)
                                                                   ^
```

However, to accomplish this, I'd overload the function with less arguments and have that call your "real" function (this is what default parameters are doing under the hood anyways):

```
template<class T>
int ExistIndex(const vector<T> v, T obj, int start = 0)                                                                                                
{
    return ExistIndex(v, obj, start, v.size() - 1);
}
```